# Need to change Load Test or Application Hosting plan

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, performance-testing, load-testing

I have hosted my application in Azure App service in `Standard: 1 Small` plan. And I run the load test on my application with below settings

```
Test duration  - 1 minutes
Response time goal - 4 sec
Step Load pattern - 100 step user per 6 sec
Maximum user count - 1000
```

from the above test configuration, I got around 800  error and `80% of them are response time exceed 4 sec error`

**My Question:**

1. Do i need to increase my plan because to achieve 4 sec response time
   goal?
2. Do i need to reconsider the response time goal of 4 sec?
3. If i need to reconsider the response time goal then what is the best
   response time goal I need to set?

Comment: Your numbers do not make sense. Is the response goal 4 minutes or 4 seconds? With a test duration of 1 minute there are only 6 intervals of 10 seconds, hence the maximum user load that can be achieved, by adding 100 every 10 seconds, is 600. This is much less than 3000.

Comment: Not sure how we can answer this here - you showed no code, and we know nothing about your app and its related moving parts (cache, database, etc), so we don't know where your bottleneck is. As written, it's anyone's guess.

Comment: @AdrianHHH Thanks for pointing out the mistakes. i have corrected with correct load test configuration.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I have posted this because I am in confusion that 4 sec response time goal can be achievable for 1000 user load. If is it possible then my current hosting plan don't pass that result so do i have turn scale up for my azure app

Comment: Are you using Application Insights in your app? If not then go add it and try again. Use the data to find the bottleneck or ramp up azure...

Comment: You are not running the test for long enough to learn anything. Only for the last 6 seconds will the load be 1000. Focussing on setting (or worrying about) the goal as 4 seconds is not useful. Run the test for longer, e.g. let it run for another minute after the 1000 users is reached and then look at the graphs and tables in the results. You will see the response times etc. displayed clearly. You will also see the range of times. I do not set response time goals in my test suite as they cause tests to fail. I use the graphs and tables to assess whether the response time goals are achieved.

Answer (score 0):

> Do i need to increase my plan because to achieve 4 sec response time goal?

Per my understanding, I assumed that you could try to [Monitor your web app in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-monitor) to collect the metrics (average memory usage, average response time, CPU time, Requests,etc.) of your web app. For increased throughput, you could leverage [Scale Out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/insights-how-to-scale) to create multiple copies of your web site and add a load balancer to distribute the requests between them automatically. Also, you could leverage [Remote Profiling in Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/remote-profiling-support-in-azure-app-service/) to find whether you could optimize your application to reduce the latency of HTTP requests. If the above steps couldn't reduce the latency, you need to change your App Service plan to a higher pricing tier for a bigger physical server with increasing numbers of cores and amounts of memory.

> If i need to reconsider the response time goal then what is the best response time goal I need to set?

As I known, higher pricing tier would bring you more performance and throughput, but it would cost you much. I assumed that you could try to optimize your application and combine with your budget and performance target (throughput,response time,etc.) for choosing the appropriate App Service plan to collect the metrics from your application. With the metrics data, you could determine that whether the average response time could meet your requirement. For more details about web app performance issue, you could refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-troubleshoot-performance-degradation).

Answer (score -2):

1. It depends on where the problem lives, you can check it using i.e. [Azure Monitoring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview) and if you find out that i.e. CPU or RAM usage is very high and therefore your app cannot serve 1000 concurrent virtual users having response time less than 4 seconds - in that case you will need to switch to more powerful hardware. If the CPU and RAM load remains relatively low - the problem lives somewhere else and you will need to consider some [performance profiling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx)
2. It is only you who can answer, it depends on your application specifics. If it is something for internal use and doing something not very important and/or urgent - it can be fine to have even 60 seconds response time.
3. The same as 3: the "goal" should be coming from the business world, i.e. you should have an explicit requirement, i.e. `application must serve X users having response time not more than Y ms", see [Gotta Test 'em All](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/gotta-test-em-all) article for details. If you don't have explicit requirements - my recommendation is making sure that your application scales, i.e. it can bear higher load given better CPU and RAM specs or if you add an extra node to the cluster.